# CATIA vb.net error inserting PowerCopy

Tags: vb.net, catia

More one time I need Help.

I'm developing something to insert a powercopy in a part, using vb.net. and this worked before. But today this error is happening:
[image: Error]

I thought that it was the references of the project. Then I removed it, and inserted it again, but some error.

I have no idea......

Comment: Every time you call BeginInstanceFactory you must also call EndInstanceFactory.

Comment: If you are debugging, and call BeginInstanceFactory, then have a problem and stop execution before EndInstanceFactory is called, it leaves CATIA is a sort of broken state and this sort of thing may happen. Try calling EndInstanceFactory before BeginInstanceFactory. It shouldn't cause trouble if it is unneeded and may avoid the problem you are having.

Comment: With that occours an error on the EndInstanceFactory, because it's ending something that isn't started. I have tried to debug this on other computer, and it works fine... Just doesn't work in my computer

Comment: Make sure you have the required license on your computer. A KT1 or PKT license is required to instantiate power copies or UDFs using VB (or KBE).

Comment: I have that license. I don't know why some times works, and another times doesn't. It's giving me crazy